# replacing an item (tensor) in a list with another tensor but of different shape, using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a list of tensors

```
t_list=[tensor([[1],
         [1],
         [1]]),
 tensor([[1],
         [1],
         [1]]),
 tensor([[1],
         [1],
         [1]])]
```

and want to convert it to

```
[tensor([[1,0,0],
         [1,0,0],
         [1,0,0]]),
 tensor([[1,0,0],
         [1,0,0],
         [1,0,0]]),
 tensor([[1,0,0],
         [1,0,0],
         [1,0,0]])]
```

I tried this code

```
import torch
z= torch.zeros(1,2)
for i, item in enumerate(t_list):
    for ii, item2 in enumerate(item):
        unsqueezed = torch.unsqueeze(item2,0)
        cat1 = torch.cat((unsqueezed,z),-1)
        squeezed = torch.squeeze(cat1,0)
        t[i][ii] = squeezed
```

But got this error

```
RuntimeError: expand(torch.FloatTensor{[5]}, size=[]): the number of sizes provided (0) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (1)
```

I am not sure how to get around this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use list comprehension, and a little "outer product" trick:

```py
t_list = [x_ * torch.tensor([[1, 0, 0]]) for x_ in t_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I stored them in a new list. Maybe it is not the best way but this is how I made it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).